# RabbitMQ creating exchanges but not queues and no subscriber receives messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, micronaut

I'm building a couple of microservices using Micronaut. A requirement on a service is that they must all produce events, but it is optional for any service to listen to events of other services. I want to build this so that locally you can plug in RabbitMQ, but when running in any environment you can use a PaaS broker.

To achieve this, I want to configure an exchange for each microservice. E.g. the product microservice will produce events to an exchange named `product_events`. This service also happens to listen to events from the payments service:

```yaml
broker:
  publish:
    exchange: product_events
  subscribe:
    exchanges:
      - payment_events
```

The publisher publishes messages to its own exchange:

```java
public void sendToTopic(final String routingKey, final String data) throws BrokerPublishException {
    final String rabbitMqFormattedRoutingKey = routingKey.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ".");
    final ConnectionFactory factory = getConnectionFactory();
    try (final Connection connection = factory.newConnection(); final Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
        LOG.info("Publishing message on exchange '{}' using routing key '{}' with data: {}", exchange, rabbitMqFormattedRoutingKey, data);
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC, true);
        channel.basicPublish(exchange, rabbitMqFormattedRoutingKey, null, data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (final IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        throw new BrokerPublishException("Failed to publish message", e);
    }
}
```

When I invoke the services controller, I can see that the message is produced and added to the exchange:

```
Publishing message on exchange 'product_events' using routing key 'product.added with data: {"aggregateId":"product"}
```

I then want the consumer to start at application startup:

```java
@Context // Eager start
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.MESSAGE_CONSUMER) // Decouple message consuming to executor
public class SubscriberService {

    private final BrokerSubscriber subscriber;

    public SubscriberService(final BrokerSubscriber subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        subscriber.receive();
    }
}
```

The RabbitMQ implementation for subscribe looks like this:

```java
public void receive() throws BrokerSubscribeException {
    final ConnectionFactory factory = getConnectionFactory();
    try (final Connection connection = factory.newConnection(); final Channel channel = connection.createChannel()){
        for (final String exchange : exchanges) {
            channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC, true);
            final String queueName = channel.queueDeclare(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), true, true, true, null).getQueue();
            channel.queueBind(queueName, exchange, "#");

            LOG.info("Waiting for messages on exchange '{}', with bound queue '{}'", exchange, queueName);

            final DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                final String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                LOG.info("Received '{}' with message\n:{}", delivery.getEnvelope().getRoutingKey(), message);
            };
            channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {});
        }
    } catch (final IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        throw new BrokerSubscribeException("Failed when subscribing to messages", e);
    }
}
```

The subscribe generates the following log message on startup:

```
Waiting for messages on exchange 'payment_events', with bound queue 'e60dc206-f757-49c7-8f3f-fee6b2f3d255'
```

Everything starts correctly, I can see the exchanges created in the management console:
[image]

But there are no queues in the console, and I can reuse the guid printed to the console and create that queue through the management console without any collisions or warnings. My services that should listen `#` on each others exchanges get no messages at all.

I can create a queue through the management console and bind that to the exchange and get messages placed by the publisher, but I cannot get my services do this.

So in a nutshell:

1. Application starts, subscriber creates exchanges and listens to `#`
2. Product service gets operation to add new product
3. Product service publishes message about added product to its own exchange
4. Payment service listens to product services exchange and should log received messages
5. Nothing happens

Is there any issue that I create two connections to the same broker in the same Micronaut application?

I really can't wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is fairly embarrassing.

The subscriber should not use try-with-resources, since the connection and the channel will be closed immediately at the end of the statement. Simply changed:

```
try (final Connection connection = factory.newConnection(); final Channel channel = connection.createChannel()){
    // Do stuff
}
```

into:

```java
try {
    final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    // Do stuff
}
```